# Permission denied on dnf search since update to fedora 26

Tags: fedora, permissions

I've just updated a VM to Fedora 26 from 25, and since then I'm getting the following error when running `dnf search` without `sudo`:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/cache/dnf/expired_repos.json'
```

The search still works mind you so it's not that big of a deal but it's still somewhat annoying. I've checked the permissions on the file and they're the same that on my other Fedora 25 VM: `-rw-r--r--. 1 root root`. Any idea where that mind be from?